# Running a unit test after changing it does not run the updated test in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit

This is super weird and only happens for one of my modules in my project.

If I change the name of a test, then right click and run the test, it will say No tests found matching Method: newName. It is effectively trying to run the old test, instead of the new one, despite the fact I'm not re-running the same Run Configuration - I'm right clicking and running the freshly edited test.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Build your project before running tests

Comment: IntelliJ runs the compiled code, not what you have latest adapted in your code. sure, adding an assertion won't cause too much of an issue, but if you renamed it without much care, your IDE might still find the previous and use that.

Comment: @Stultuske Indeed that is the case, but for other modules it automatically picks up the changed name without needing to be rebuilt - why is this? How can I make it so that this module also doesn't need to be rebuilt for the updated test to be run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Snap]

In Run Configuration, add Build Project so that it picks up latest changes

Comment: Surely if this was the issue it would be happening for all run configurations - including for other modules? But it is only for this one module?

Comment: Please check your Project Structure > Modules. Also in your Run Configuration ensure that you use classpath of module

Comment: I can confirm that it does build project in the run configuration already, so that isn't the fix. Will check your latest suggestion now. However as a side note, these all require editing a run configuration - but what about when there is no run configuration? When I just run a test directly on the method and IDEA generates the run configuration itself? There must be some generic fix so that these run without having to edit the generated run configuration afterwards?

Comment: Yea, there is a default configuration for Tests. The "Run/Debug" configuration dialog has tree of configurations on the left side.
One of the nodes is called Defaults/Templates.

If you expand it, you can edit the defaults for any kind of run configuration type, including "JUnit test".